# What is the difference render() and redirect() in Django?

Tags: django

What's difference between

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.user = request.user
        order.save()
        return redirect('orders:success')
```

and

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.user = request.user
        order.save()
        return render(
            request,
            'orders/success.html',
            {}
        )
```

I think these are totally same.

Any difference?

Comment: as a newbie I think is quite clear why one would think they are the same: or more specifically why they would have the same end result in this case. I too am trying to figure out which is preferred...

Answer (score 12):

Both are totally different where the redirect gives the HttpResponseRedirect for 
the argument you have passed.

example

```
return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

takes you to the https://example.com/ page

```
 return render(request,'/result.html',{'foo':'bar'})
```

renders the context dictionary in to the template 'result.html' and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text

result.html
...
{foo}
...
where foo will replaced by bar

For more details look in to this [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Answer (score 10):

The render function `Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.`

You request a page and the `render` function returns it.

The `redirect` function sends another request to the given url.